# Calculating cell values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I am trying to write VBA code for reading a value from a different worksheet and then calculating a value in the current one. The code I wrote:

```
Function tell_me2()
Dim my_range As Range
Dim sheet_number As Integer
Dim my_row As Integer
Dim my_column As Integer
Dim my_value As Integer
sheet_number = ActiveSheet.Index
my_row = ActiveCell.Row
my_column = ActiveCell.Column
'MsgBox (sheet_number)
'MsgBox (my_row)
'MsgBox (my_column)
'MsgBox (Worksheets(sheet_number - 1).Cells(my_row, my_column - 1))
my_value = Worksheets(sheet_number - 1).Cells(my_row, my_column - 1)
'my_value = my_range.Value
MsgBox ("12 " & my_value)
'my_range = Worksheets(sheet_number - 1).Cells(my_row - 1, my_column - 1)
'my_range.Activate
Set my_range = Worksheets(sheet_number).Cells(my_row, my_column + 1)
' have also tried
Worksheets(sheet_number).Cells(my_row, my_column + 1) = my_value - 12
my_range.Value = my_value - 12
MsgBox ("All Done!")
End Function
```

When debugging I can see that my_value contains the correct value but then I get a #VALUE error rather than the value I want in the correct cell.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You simply miss an output for your function, in VBA, it is simply like this :

```
Name_of_the_Function = OutPut
```

`OutPut` can be any kind of variable, so your code will look like this :

```
Sub tell_me2()
Dim my_range As Range
Dim sheet_number As Integer
Dim my_row As Long
Dim my_column As Long
Dim my_value As Integer

sheet_number = ActiveSheet.Index
my_row = ActiveCell.Row
my_column = ActiveCell.Column

my_value = Worksheets(sheet_number - 1).Cells(my_row, my_column - 1)


Set my_range = Worksheets(sheet_number).Cells(my_row, my_column + 1)
MsgBox my_range.Address
my_range.Value = my_value - 12


MsgBox ("All Done!")
End Sub
```

Comment: This makes no difference; I do not want the function to return a value, I just want it to set the value of the cell. I believe the problem is in the following line: [code]Worksheets(sheet_number).Cells(my_row, my_column + 1) = my_value - 12[/code]

Comment: Mkay so, you don't use it as a function in Excel nor in VBA, so in fact it is a sub. Give the edit a try!

Comment: You are perfectly right, this did the trick. I can't believe I was missing something so obvious! Many thanks again!

Comment: @user3474704 : Missing the obvious is most of the time the first problem of a developer so don't worry! ;) Just take minute to take the tour and to know how SO works (accepting answers and voting) : http://stackoverflow.com/tour